# Translation/meaning of 叫阮的名 song by 巫啟賢

Tags: translation, meaning, hokkien, songs

What is the meaning/translation  of the song lyrics. I grew up listening to this song and it brings me great memories. However, I do not know Hokkien. If you are willing to share or point me to a webpage which has translated the lyrics to English, that'd be great! Thank you.

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMmbIU8NqIU

Lyrics:

谁在叫阮的名 一句比一句痛

亲像在问阮甘会惊寒

不需要别人来讲 阮心内嘛知影

是你的声 是你的声

谁住在阮的梦 一住就一世人

尚惊日头会将咱拆散

虽然离开那呢远 阮犹原会知影

是你的影 是你的影

叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

谁在叫阮的名 一句比一句痛

亲像在问阮甘会惊寒

不需要别人来讲 阮心内嘛知影

是你的声 是你的声

谁住在阮的梦 一住就一世人

尚惊日头会将咱拆散

虽然离开那呢远 阮犹原会知影

是你的影 是你的影

叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

Comment: [https://www.zhihu.com/question/264569144/answer/282667389](https://www.zhihu.com/question/264569144/answer/282667389) The traditional Chinese version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 谁在叫阮的名 一句比一句痛

(Who calls our name. Calling one sentence is more painful than the former one.)

> 亲像在问阮甘会惊寒

(Just like asking us whether we are cold.)

> 不需要别人来讲 阮心内嘛知影

(There is no need for other people's words. We know in the bottom of our hearts.)

> 是你的声 是你的声

(It is your voice. It is your voice.)

> 谁住在阮的梦 一住就一世人

(Who lives in our dream. Once it lives, it lives for entire live.)

> 尚惊日头会将咱拆散

(The most fearful is that sun will separate us apart.)

> 虽然离开那呢远 阮犹原会知影

(Although the departure is far. We still can know.)

> 是你的影 是你的影

(It is your appearance. It is your appearance.)

> 叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

(Calling our name. We spend our entire life to listen carefully.)

> 当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

(At the beginning of the time when I was a child, It is too late to let you know that you are our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

(Calling our name. We need your company.)

> 人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

(We want you to hold our hands to pass the road of our lives.)

> 谁在叫阮的名 一句比一句痛

(Who calls our name. Calling one sentence is more painful than the former one.)

> 亲像在问阮甘会惊寒

(Just like asking us whether we are cold.)

> 不需要别人来讲 阮心内嘛知影

(There is no need for other people's words. We know in the bottom of our hearts.)

> 是你的声 是你的声

(It is your voice. It is your voice.)

> 谁住在阮的梦 一住就一世人

(Who lives in our dream. Once it lives, it lives for entire live.)

> 尚惊日头会将咱拆散

(The most fearful is that sun will separate us apart.)

> 虽然离开那呢远 阮犹原会知影

(Although the departure is far. We still can know.)

> 是你的影 是你的影

(It is your appearance. It is your appearance.)

> 叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

(Calling our name. We spend our entire life to listen carefully.)

> 当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

(At the beginning of the time when I was a child, It is too late to let you know that you are our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

(Calling our name. We need your company.)

> 人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

(We want you to hold our hands to pass the road of our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

(Calling our name. We spend our entire life to listen carefully.)

> 当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

(At the beginning of the time when I was a child, It is too late to let you know that you are our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

(Calling our name. We need your company.)

> 人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

(We want you to hold our hands to pass the road of our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮用一生斟酌听

(Calling our name. We spend our entire life to listen carefully.)

> 当初细汉未赴乎你了解 你是阮的生命

(At the beginning of the time when I was a child, It is too late to let you know that you are our lives.)

> 叫阮的名 阮需要你来作伴

(Calling our name. We need your company.)

> 人生的路途阮爱你牵阮走

(We want you to hold our hands to pass the road of our lives.)